# "Cannot execute command" popup from IntelliJ when launching Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-desktop

I'm getting a strange error popup I suspect it has something to do with a built in integration of Docker in IntelliJ.

I'm running the following:

- Mac OS Big Sur 11.4
- IntelliJ 21.1.3
- Docker Desktop 3.5.2.18
- Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

When I launch Docker Desktop, it launches IntelliJ for some reason and I get an error popup immediately:

**Title:** *Cannot execute command*

**Body:** *Can not open file /Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/--list-extensions*

I've tried reinstalling both several times and used the Clear cache and clear data options in the Docker settings. I should also note that i've tried removing all projects from IntelliJ and docker and have even disabled the "Docker" plugin in IntelliJ but still get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent this popup on launch? It is more of an annoyance than a blocker as I can simply close it and then use the tools without problems but its odd that this would happen. Originally I dismissed it as some random system specific configuration but today found that it is not specific to my environment as I got it on a fresh install on a new machine with new user.

Comment: It doesn't look related to IntelliJ IDEA Docker integration. Likely some extension/file type is associated with IntelliJ IDEA and Docker Desktop starts the IDE to handle it.

Comment: Does a file extension/type association still seem applicable if I have no images in docker nor am opening any files? It's a first launch of docker desktop when intellij is also installed.

Comment: It's some system level association not specific to Docker or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I thought IntelliJ Docker integration even when disabled in intellij due to some possible hooks via entries in some docker launch script if anyone might be familiar

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to narrow it down or resolve? This machine is a fresh reinstall with Docker and IntelliJ so I don't understand how it can be anything other than related to their associations/launch scripts.

Comment: Could be related to https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/. I would file a bug with Docker.

Comment: You can also try resetting Docker settings to factory defaults: https://i.imgur.com/SC8bE2Y.png.

Comment: In the spirit of trying to make a workaround for this infuriating problem, is there a way of listing all file types associated with IntelliJ on macOS and perhaps deleting the "type" from the question?

Comment: Bug report: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5840.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems a bug of Docker Development Environments Preview. The IntelliJ IDEA is opened by this process.

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.dev-envs
```

You can degrade the Docker Desktop to version [3.4.0](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-340) to temporarily fix this problem.

Comment: also fixed in Docker [3.6.0](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-360)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me today:

- Upgrade to Big Sur (wanted to do that anyway).
- Remove Intelli-J
- Uninstall Docker
- Install Docker 3.6.x
- Install latest Intelli-J

Problem gone.

Comment: Hmm, after all, behaviour changed. when I open Docker Desktop, it now opens a file (--list-extensions) in IDEA (try About Docker Desktop for instance). Docker seems to run ok all together, but it's an annoying popup.

Comment: Upgrading to Docker [3.6.0](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-360) alone fixed it for m.